# jqplot not able to display the chart properly

Tags: jquery, jqplot

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var firstv=10;
            var secondv=20;
            var thirdv=70;
            var name1=ram;
            var name2=kumar;
            var name3=manju;
      var data = [ [name1, firstv],[name2, secondv], [name3, thirdv]];

var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart', [data],
        {
            grid: {
                shadow: false,
                background: '#FFFFFF',                                                                                          
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                // Make this a pie chart.
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    showDataLabels: true,
                    padding: 20,
                    startAngle: 270
                }
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 'e',
                fontSize: 11,
                marginTop: 10,                                
            }
        });
});
```

[working code link](http://jsfiddle.net/Rxm3L/25/)

if i assign values to var , it is not fetching it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to store a string instead?

```
var secondv=20;
var thirdv=70;
var name1=ram; //  var name1='ram';
var name2=kumar; // var name2='kumar';
var name3=manju; // var name3='manju';
```

If not where are you getting those variables from?

and if you are just using those values once. You can directly assign them in data

```
var data = [
    ["ram", 10], 
    ["kumar", 20],
    ["manju", 70]
];​
```

Comment: and how to merge to values to a single name using jqplot

Comment: I mean `ram`, `kumar`, and `manju`.. are those variables? or just a string you want to assign to a variable

Comment: secondv and thirdv... m speaking about

Comment: `var data = [["ram", 10],["kumar", 90]];` ​like this? Sorry I'm confused to what you are asking

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16835/discussion-between-dude-and-wirey)

Comment: merging them to a single color and add up the value

Answer (score 1):

Check the error console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ram is not defined
```

Change your assignment of names to quoted names:

```
var name1="ram";
var name2="kumar";
var name3="manju";
```

[Here is the updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/kXrfR/).